# Cocoa Touch text view with aligned, justified text

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

I am trying to create a textview with predefined height that will contain justified text.

When entering the text into the view, I need to be able to check when the view is full.

How would I do this? Core Text?

I am using sdk-3.2.

Comment: Core Text doesn't exist (in public, at least) on the iPhone. Are you talking about Cocoa (on the Mac) or Cocoa Touch (on the iPhone)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am using SDK 3.2 for ipad/phone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using `UITextView` (that would be the most "logical" way to do it), or any others SDK current classes.

The only simple way to do it if to put the content to be justified in an html file, justify it using CSS, and show it in a `UIWebView`.

Comment: I thought about this, but here the problem is to check whether the box has been filled. I could check the height using 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString' but that may only be done once the webview has finished loading, so I don't think this will work.